# Union of two lists containing objects

Tags: java, collections, java-6

I have two list

```
ListA<TestData> listA = new ArrayList<TestData>()
ListB<TestData> listB = new ArrayList<TestData>()
```

both contain object of type TestData and TestData contain these variables.

```
TestData {
    String status;
    String billType;
}
```

I want union of the two lists.

```
ListA = ["ACTV","S"],["DISC","E"];

ListB = ["ACTV","V"],["DISC","E"],["DISC","S"];

UpdatedList = ["ACTV","S"],["DISC","E"],["ACTV","V"],["DISC","S"];
```

I tried by checking below condition but it is not working.

```
for (TestData myData : ListA) {
        if(!ListB.contains(myData))
            return true;
    }
```

Can you please let me know the correct and efficient way to merge the list. or this can be achievable my using some other collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Set` and let `TestData` override `equals` and `hashCode` to avoid the duplicates.

```
TestData {
   String status;
   String billType;

   public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
      if (obj == null || !(obj instanceof Testdata)) return false;
      TestData other = (TestData) obj;

      return status.equals(other.getStatus()) && billType.equals(other.getBillType())
   }

   public int hashCode() {
      int hashcode = 31;
      hashcode += 31 * status.length();
      hashcode += 31 * billType.length();
      return hashcode;
   }
}
```

and then

```
Set<TestData> data = new HashSet<>();
data.addAll(listA);
data.addAll(listB);
```

If you want a sorted `TreeSet` then implement `Comparable` instead where you compare in a similar way as the `equals` method.

Answer (score 2):

You should override **equals()** method to work with **contains()** method.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29

You could do override **equals()** and **hashCode()** method in your class and then put all the lists to Set.

```
Set<TestData> uniqueElements = new HashSet<>();

uniqueElements.addAll(listA);
uniqueElements.addAll(listB);
```

Comment: This is the only answer that notes that the `equals()` method needs to be overridden in all cases. If `HashSet` is used, then `hashCode()` should be overridden; if `TreeSet` is used, then `Comparable<>` needs to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 ListA.addAll(ListB);
```

This adds all elements on Collection B to A. But List is an interface that allows repeated values.

If you want to ensure not having repeated items you must Overwrite equals method on your TestData class and use Sets (like HashSet) instead of Lists.

Off topic, in Java, variable names start in lowercase, see javacode conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: this will not ignore duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You can also use apache commons collections if you are at liberty to use external library

```
ListUtils.union(listA , listB);
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#union(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)